# Adding a new role with administrator's capabilities

Tags: user-roles

I'm trying to add a new role to my website that is based on administrator's role. I want my new role to have all the capabilities admin has. Problem is, when I log in with my new user, I can't access the admin dashboard. I can only change my profile. Here's my code:

```
function quick_remove_role() {
    remove_role( 'manager' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'quick_remove_role' );

if ( ! ( role_exists( 'manager' ) ) ) {
    function new_role_manager() {
        global $wp_roles;

        if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) ) {
            $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
        }

        $adm = $wp_roles->get_role( 'administrator' );

        $wp_roles->add_role( 'manager', 'Gestionnaire', $adm->capabilities );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'new_role_manager' );
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but note that your `if ( ! ( role_exists( 'manager' ) ) )` check executes when the file is loaded - so if the role exists, then the logic to re-create the role will never be set up, but the role will still be removed when `init` fires. In effect, this means that your role only exists before `init` fires for one request, then only after `init` for the next, then before `init` for the next... ad infinitum. As an aside, you can also use the `add_role()`/`get_role()` wrappers directly instead of using the `WP_Roles` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. It had to do with my function that removes the manager role. I commented it out, and it works. My bad. Here's the working code:

```
if ( ! ( role_exists( 'manager' ) ) ) {
    function new_role_manager() {
        global $wp_roles;

        if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) ) {
            $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
        }

        $adm = $wp_roles->get_role( 'administrator' );

        $wp_roles->add_role( 'manager', 'Gestionnaire', $adm->capabilities );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'new_role_manager' );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about [renaming](https://wpmudev.com/blog/change-wordpress-role-names/) 'administrator' role to 'manager' or use [role editor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/roles/)?